# Counting Sequences (recurrence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, contest-math

Compute the number of sequences of real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_{16}$ satisfying the condition that for every positive integer $n$,
$$
a_1^n + a_2^{2n} + \dots + a_{16}^{16n} = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 10^{n+1} + 10^n + 1 & \text{for even } n \\ 10^n - 1 & \text{for odd } n \end{array} \right. .
$$
Source: NIMO Summer 2012

A solution of the problem proceeds by the recurrence:

> It's a recurrence, so it's $a_{n+1}=100a_n \pm 99$. Adding consecutives, gives $a_n=-a_{n-1} +100(a_{n-2}+1)$.
> Characteristic equation: $x^3+x^2-100(x+1)=0$.

In particular, I wish to know how this recurrence is established or is there any other way to approach this problem.

Thankyou!

Comment: $a_n+1=100a_n\pm99$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is how someone on a discussion thread presented their solution. It may/may not be correct

Comment: Wait – so, you think $a_n+1=100a_n\pm99$ could be correct? It implies $99a_n=1\pm99$, so $a_n=(1/99)\pm1$ for all $n$ – do you think that could be correct? This isn't rocket science, it's something you can well and truly completely understand all by yourself, with nobody helping you, and that's the first step to getting something done in Mathematics. I strongly suspect that what you have written is not what "someone" intended to write.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, that was a fault in latex on my end. It's actually intended to be $a_{n+1}$. However if you still suspect this is what someone intended to write, you can check the link here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h502886p2825383

Comment: OK, with your edit it looks much better.

Comment: I claim that there are lots of errors with their writeup, which makes it hard to decipher (without already knowing what is happening). See my solution for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, state what you've tried and why it doesn't seem to work.)

**First, an alternative solution/approach to the stated portion.**

Let $b_i = a_i ^i$.
Let the sum of the $n$th powers be denoted as $ s_n = \sum b_i ^n$.

Claim: More generally, for any set of $ \{ s_i \}_{i=1}^{16}$, there is a unique solution (up to permutation) in complex numbers to $ \sum_{i=1}^{16} b_i ^n  = s_n$ for $n = 1$ to 16.
Proof: Use Newton's identities to determine the coefficients of the degree 16 polynomial who roots are $b_i$.
Thus, $ \{b_i\}$ are the roots, including multiplicity, of the polynomial, so are uniquely determined.

Claim: By observation, the solution is $\{ b_i \} = \{ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0 \}$.
Proof: Well, you can verify it after the fact.
To guess it, using wishful thinking for now, given the simplicity of the setup, we hope that they are of the form $\pm 10, \pm 1 \pm 0$,
We're lucky that this works out, and that previous claim tells us the solution is unique.

Notes

- In fact, all that we needed was the first 16 equations. We didn't need them for all $n$. (This should be known at the start, as it follows from Newton's identities.)
- The (more) challenging part is to count the number of solutions for $ \{ a_i ^i\}$. It is mostly just case checking, as Evan demonstrated in the link.

---

**Explanation of what they were thinking of**

Note: There are lots of errors in what they wrote, so it's not surprising that you can't make sense of it. For now, ignore it.

Claim: Observe that $ s_{n+2} = 100 s_n + (-1)^{n+1} 99$ .
Proof: Splitting by $n$ odd/even, it is natural to consider $s_{n+2} - 100 s_n$, and we observe that it is equal to $(-1)^{n+1} 99$.

Claim: $s_{n+3} - 100 s_{n+1}  = (-1)^{n+2} 99 = - (s_{n+2} - 100 s_n)$.
Proof: Direct.

Corollary: Considering the recurrence in $s_n$, the characteristic equation is $ 0 = x^3 + x^2 - 100x - 100 = (x+1)(x-10)(x+10)$.
Corollary: $s_n = 6\times 10^n + 5 \times (-10^n) + 1\times (-1)^n$, by checking $ n = 1, 2, 3$.
Corollary: $\{ b_i \} = \{ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0 \}$.

---

**Errors in their writeup, which should be clear from reading the above:**

- The identity is for $s_n$, not for $a_n$.
- The identity should have been $ s_{n+2} = 100 s_n \pm 99$, not $ s_{n+1}$.
- That is not the characteristic equation for their stated recurrence. It is the characteristic equation for my stated recurrence.

Comment: Wow! That is actually pretty easy to understand and intuitive after reading your answer. Thankyou so much for your help! :) I can conclude the correct answer now.